# rails autocomplete how to use exising record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, model-associations

I'm new to rails , and I have a problem with the nested forms and all of that.
I have a User model, and an Organization model.
When I want to create a user, I want to specify from which organization does he comes from.
Either the organization name is already in the database or if it's not, I want to create a new record and associate that record the User model.

I have hard time understanding all the relations (many-to-many etc) implications in the rails framework, but so far I've got this.

**model/organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :user  

   validates_presence_of :name


end
```

**model/user.rb (short)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
    #####
end
```

From this, in the console, I can create user and specify and organization name , and it will create a new record for the user and a new record for the organization.
The problem is that it **creates a new organization each time**.

I want to be able to associate an already existing organization to a new user.
I can get the list of organization with things like typeahead.js for the form, so the name will be the same when the user selects one. But I don't know how to relate the two (the newly created user and already existing organization).

I thought of putting a hidden field with the id of the organization, and check in the controller if this id exists. If it does, put this id, if it doesn't create a new one. But I don't even know how to do this. In the console, when I update the attributes of a user, for example , with an organization_id = 3 which exists :

```
u.update_attributes( :organization_attributes => { id: 3 } )
```

It rejects saying he didn't find a user with ID=... with Organization.id = 3 ... 
I don't understand.

I suppose since this is a common case, that this should be easy , but it's messing with my head.

If someone is willing to explain to me, I'd be very grateful.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
i've just tried something in my controller but that doesn't work either.

```
 def create

    @user = User.new(user_params) # :user object built from user inputform        
    org = Organization.find_by(name:user_params[:organization_attributes][:name])
    if org 
        @user.organization.id = org.id
    end
    if @user.save
        # signin the user (token etc)
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Registration sucessfull !"
        redirect_to @user 
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

+**user_controller (strong params)**

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:lname,:email,:fname,:password,:password_confirmation,
                                 :gender,:role,:display_private,:link_li,:country,:city,:phone,:hobbies,
                                :avatar,:org_name, :organization_attributes => [ :id, :name])
end
```

+**form.html.erb**

```
<%= u.fields_for :organization do |o| %>
                                <%= o.label "Organization" %>
                                <!-- PUT ORGA -->
                                <%= o.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It should be `has_many :users` in Organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a custom method for this:

```
#in User
def organization_name
  (org = self.organization) && org.name
end

def organization_name=(name)
  if org = Organization.find_by_name(name)
    self.organization = org
  else
    self.organization = Organization.create(:name => name)
  end
end
```

Now, because you've got a getter and setter method (ie two methods with the same name, apart from the = sign), you can treat `organization_name` like an attribute of User and put it in a form field like

```
f.input :organization_name
```

The input will get the current value from `@user.organization_name` and will call `@user.organization_name=` with the new value.

Comment: Let me try this then ... =) But I've done an edit, and for me my solution should work but it doesn't , there's something i dont get ..

Answer (score 0):

First take away the accepts_nested_attributes from the model.
Then in your controller you should do something like:

```
def create

    @user = User.new(user_params) # :user object built from user inputform        
    org = Organization.where(name: user_params[:organization_attributes][:name]).first || Organization.create(name: user_params[:organization_attributes][:name])
    @user.organization = org

    if @user.save
        # signin the user (token etc)
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Registration sucessfull !"
        redirect_to @user 
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Try this out. I just edited based on the controller code you just posted.

Comment: Good eye, missed the .first.

Comment: It's basically the same thing i've done in the controller but it didn't work out in the console. PLUS i think this solution creates a new organization record each time, and just relate to the previously existed after ...

Answer (score 0):

In your app/model/user.rb

```
def self.create(name, attribute1, ... ,organization)
   user = User.new(:name => name, :atr_1 => attribute_1, ....:atr_n => attribute_n)
   user.organization = organization
   raise "user not created" if !user.save
   user
end
```

In users_controller.rb

```
def create
   org = Organization.find params['organization'] #expecting the param to be Organization#id
   user = User.create(params['name'], ..., org)
   render :json => {:message => "user created"}
end
```